# Preparing data from web form to insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I realize this question has been asked and answered to death, but my variation is a bit different.

I am creating a small application to capture a few strings from users.  All the data being captured is from simple text input.  This data will be stored in a mysql database using php.  However, unlike the other questions asked on this topic, this data will never be used for anything other than downloading to csv.  It will never be displayed on a web page, nor used to execute a script.  There is no password or login or anything.  The form will exist for a small amount of time and the target audience is a local community of a few dozen people.

My question is that due to the simplicity of this application, would cleaning the data with mysqli_real_escape_string be enough to prevent an injection or other detrimental action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should push all input content (file_put_contents) to file and store file path to download later, don't need to use database for that simple task.

Comment: I do most of my works with other frameworks which involve databases that I totally overlooked this simple, obvious, solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best function in my opinion for preventing sql injection is:

```
htmlspecialchars();
```

So if you are obtaining this information from a form using the POST method, the following code should be secure enough for you:

```
$value1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['value1']);
$value2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['value2']);
$value3 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['value3']);
//and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you should use mysqli_real_escape_string as it is intended for the use. Also, for added security, you should create and array having "BLACKLISTED" keywords and run a regex check against them before mysqli_real_escape_string.